# C++ Clear all browser cookies with batch script

Tags: javascript, c++, batch-file, cookies

Hi all i need a help with clearing cookies with c++ program and i find some ways to do it in batch file but i don't think it may works in all pcs as the code is definded with storing dir but what if the user has installed windows drive D:/ ?

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/clear-privacy-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-safari/

```
set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"
```

Like in above code so can someone show a effect way to clear cookies if possible just clear cookies of given website from all major browsers i re-searched alot but couldn't find any result which i wanted so please help me guys.

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before looking at answer below : Why do you want to delete "User
>   Data"? Instead delete specific cache files?

You need to look at %appdata% - do not worry about C:\ or D:\

But it points to something like : C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming

So go up one dir and from there go to Local\Google\Chrome to delete User Data

```
@echo off
pushd %appdata%
cd..
if exist "%cd%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" (
rmdir /s /q "%cd%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
)
popd
```

If you want to delete cookies set by a specific website you can use below batch script :

```
    @echo off
set /p yoursite="What is the website that you want to delete the cookies for ? Just type without 'www': "
if exist resetErrorLevel.bat (
  break > resetErrorLevel.bat
)
echo exit /b 0 >> resetErrorLevel.bat
if exist %USERPROFILE%\Cookies\* (
  :loop
  for /f "tokens=*" %%L in ('dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies"') do (
        if exist %%L\* (
            rem a directory!
         )  else (
                if "%%~xL" EQU ".txt" (
                    if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies\%%L" (
                       call resetErrorLevel.bat
                       for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A in (%USERPROFILE%\Cookies\%%L) do (
                         echo.%%A | findstr /c:"%yoursite%" >nul
                         if errorlevel 1 ( 
                                  echo Deleting file ...
                                  del /q /s /f "%USERPROFILE%\Cookies\%%L" 
                                  goto :loop
                               )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
    )

    del resetErrorLevel.bat
)
```

Just copy the above script in deletecookies.bat and run it, it will ask you to input a specific website, if you want to delete for yahoo.com, just type 'yahoo.com' and NOT www.yahoo.com

Comment: Well is it possible to delete just cookies of just a specific site?

Comment: I get the error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: When you delete user data ? or cookies?

Comment: well /f switch on rmdir will actually delete ? But some files may have been being used by the current chrome window. So you need to close chrome before you delete the remaining.

Comment: is there any way to make it forcefully delete it without closing chrome?

Comment: You cannot if Chrome acquires a lock on the file you are deleting. Take an example of a word document which is open for editing. Now go and try deleting it while the word doc is open. You will see.